# Anylogic - line of sight

Tags: anylogic

Is there a way to check if there is a line of sight between two agents assuming some buildings and presentation markup?
(Meaning a function that would check if two agents can see each other assuming buildings and walls)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I did it once in the past. The only problem is that it might be slow if you need to do that calculation thousands of times per second. And it's only in 2D. If you need 3D, the idea is not so different.

1) add all your building nodes and everything that might be an obstacle between the two agents to a collection. You may want to put a rectangular node around your buildings to keep everything in one collection (assuming you are using space markup with nodes)

2) generate a delta distance delta (equal to 1 for example) and find the angle of the line that passes through both agents.

3) Make a loop from the position of agent1 till the position of agent2. It will be something like this:

```
L=delta;
while(L<LThatReachesSecondAgent){
    x1 = agent1.getX() + L*cos(angle);
    y1 = agent1.getY() + L*sin(angle);
    for(Node n : yourCollectionOfNodes){
         If(n.contains(x1,y1))
             return false
    }
/*This can also work maybe faster
//int numNodesInTheWay=count(yourCollectionOfNodes,n->n.contains(x1,y1));
//if(numNodesInTheWay>0) return false
*/
    L+=delta;
}
return true
```

Comment: interesting, and two points; 1- you can do this without calculating the angle of the line that passes through both agents. 2- in order to make it faster, you can use a zoned environment, and do the above `for` loop only for those nodes in possible zones, not all of them. something like this:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/kOL1L.png

Answer (score 0):

welcome to SOF.

No, there is no build-in function, afaik. You would have to code something manually, which is possible but not straight forward. If you want help with that, you need to provide more details on the specifics.